# BeanValidation Error - JSR 303 Bean validation implementation not found on classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, vaadin, bean-validation

I´m working on this Vaadin Tutorial series.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-DxZ1reIdM&list=PLcRrh9hGNallPtT2VbUAsrWqvkQ-XE22h&index=11

Text Version: https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/modern-web-apps-with-spring-boot-and-vaadin/vaadin-form-data-binding-and-validation?

I´m trying to use Binding but I get the following error in my Terminal:

```
2020-11-22 09:11:11.012  INFO 38103 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator  : The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
2020-11-22 09:11:11.373  INFO 38103 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.vaadin.validator.BeanValidator       : A JSR-303 bean validation implementation not found on the classpath or could not be initialized. BeanValidator cannot be used.
```

more below the next:

```
Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

How do I add a [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) provider? I´m working with vaadin as a maven project same as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by adding the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: *Spring Boot* brings in a *ton* of libraries unrelated to *Jakarta Validation* (*Bean Validation*). See the [Answer by Leviand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77919677/642706) for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

### *Hibernate Validator*

Adding the whole `spring-boot-starter-validation` is a little bit overkill.

You can simply add the [*Hibernate Validator*](https://hibernate.org/validator/), which will add the minimum amount of libraries to your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>yourHibernateVersion</version>
</dependency>
```

This approach is suggested by the Vaadin company itself, as you can see [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/binding-data/components-binder-beans#using-jsr-303-bean-validation).

*Hibernate Validator* serves as the only implementation of [*Jakarta Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/) (formerly known as *Bean Validation*) specification versions 2.0, 3.0, and upcoming 3.1.